# freebsd pw adduser command and python file descriptors

Tags: python, freebsd

I'm trying to write a system management script in Python 2.7 on FreeBSD and I'm stuck trying to programmatically set the user's password when adding them. I'm using the FreeBSD pw command which has a -h flag which accepts a file descriptor as an argument.

The route I was taking is using Python's subprocess module, but I 
seem to be getting stuck in that Python treats everything as strings
and the pw -h option is expecting a fd (file descriptor) back.
The command I'm trying to run is:

```
/usr/sbin/pw useradd foobar2 -C /usr/local/etc/bsdmanage/etc/pw.conf -m -c "BSDmanage foobar2 user" -G foobar2-www -h
```

I'm doing this via:

```
objTempPassFile = open(strTempDir + 'foobar.txt', 'w+')
objTempPassFile.write(strTempPass)
objTempPassFile.seek(0)

listCmdArgs = shlex.split(strPwUserCmd)
processUser = subprocess.Popen(listCmdArgs,stdin=objTempPassFile.fileno(),stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
strOutPut, strErrorValue = processUser.communicate()
```

where `strPwUserCmd` is the above pw command and `strTempPass` is just a string.

I also tried passing the password string as an option to `Popen.communicate()` and changing stdin to `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`

I also tried using a StringIO object. However, passing that either gets errors about it not being a valid I/O object or the pw commands fails and doesn't see any arguments passed to the -h switch.

[FreeBSD pw manpage](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pw%288%29)

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: As usual. Poked at it, re-read the docs and was on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you use the -h 0 flag to pw it prompts for stdin pipe and then you just use process.communicate(string) to pass the password in.

So, like this:

```
/usr/sbin/pw useradd foobar2 -C /usr/local/etc/bsdmanage/etc/pw.conf -m -c "BSDmanage foobar2 user" -G foobar2-www -h 0
```

as the command string. Then call that via:

```
listCmdArgs = shlex.split(strPwUserCmd)
processUser = subprocess.Popen(listCmdArgs,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
strOutPut, strErrorValue = processUser.communicate(strTempPass)
```

and have `strTempPass` be the password string. `strPwUserCmd` is the above 'pw' command string.